# How many times does the graph of $x = t^2 - t - 6$, $y = 2t, -5 < t < 5$ cross the $y$-axis?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, polar-coordinates, random-graphs

Although I know that it will pass through $y$-axis twice, when $t = - 2$ at $(0, - 4)$ and when $t = 3$ at $(0, 6)$ but what is the explanation to it?

Comment: Solve the quadratic equation $t^{2}-t-6=0$.

Comment: It will cross the y-axis when $x=0$. That is, when $t^2-t-6=0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

The graph crossing the $y$-axis for some $t_0$ means that $t_0$ verifies $x(t_0)=t_0^2-t_0-6=0$ (in other worths, when the $x$ coordinate is $0$).
So we solve the quadratic equation:
$$t^2-t-6=0$$
$$t=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{25}}{2} \longrightarrow t=3, t=-2.$$
This two values for $t$ verify that $-5<t<$, so we conclude your graph crosses the $y$-axis at two diferent points.

We know this two points are $(0,6)$ and $(0,-4)$ because $y=2t$ by your graph's definition, so:
$$t=3 \longrightarrow y=6 \longrightarrow \text{point } (0,6)$$
$$t=-2 \longrightarrow y=-4 \longrightarrow \text{point } (0,-4)$$

Comment: $t = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt25} {2}$, not $\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt25} {2}$. You can also write $t^2 - t - 6 = 0$ as $(t-3)(t+2) = 0$

Comment: @MathLover Oh, you're right, sorry I misswrote it. I've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminating $t$, you see this is an arc of the parabola with equation
$$4x=(y-1)^2-25,\quad -10< y<10$$
The intersections of a conic with any line are atmost two. In the present case, the intersections with the $y$-axis are obtained solving $\:(y-1)^2-25=0$.